# How can I return ArrayList values from a Class in Java

Tags: arraylist

Here's my code: The code should return the list of students with the relevant data from the arraylist. But the error is telling me it can't make a static reference to a non static method??

I've tried to make the methods static and it gives me another error.

```
//main function code
    String forename = null;
    String surname = null;
    String grade = null;
    String yesOrNo;
    double mark;
    int selection;

ArrayList<StudentClass> studentDetails = new ArrayList<StudentClass>();

switch(selection){
case 1: {
    if (studentDetails.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No Students Have Been Entered Yet");
        main(null);
        break;
                }
    else{
         for(int i = 0; i < studentDetails.size(); i++){
             StudentClass = studentDetails.get(i);
             System.out.println( StudentClass.getForename() + " " +
             StudentClass.getSurname() + " received a " + StudentClass.getGrade() +
             " for their Student Mark of " + StudentClass.getMark() + "." );
            }
        }
break;
\\ Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
StudentClass cannot be resolved to a variable
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getForename() from the   type StudentClass
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSurname() from the type StudentClass
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getGrade() from the type StudentClass
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getMark() from the type StudentClass

at students.main(students.java:60)
\\code for Class
public class  StudentClass {
      public String Forename;
      public String Surname;
      public  String Grade;
       public  double Mark;

public StudentClass(String forename, String surname, double mark){

       Forename = forename;
   Surname = surname;
   Mark = mark;
   }

  public void setForename(String forename)
    {
        Forename= forename;
    }

  public void setSurname(String surname)
    {
        Surname= surname;
    }

  public void setMark(double mark)
    {
        Mark= mark;
    }

  public  String getForename()
    {
        return Forename;
    }

  public  String getSurname()
    {
        return Surname;
    }

  public  double getMark()
    {
        return Mark;
    }
  public  String getGrade()
    {   
            if ( Mark < 40 )
                Grade = "FAIL";
            else if ( (Mark >= 40) && (Mark <= 64) )
                Grade ="PASS";
            else if ( (Mark >= 65) && (Mark <= 84) )
                Grade ="MERIT";
            else if ( (Mark >= 85) && (Mark <= 100) )
                Grade ="DISTINCTION";
            return Grade;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`StudentClass = studentDetails.get(i);` makes no sense. `StudentClass` is a classname.

You need an instance: `StudentClass student = studentDetails.get(i);` Then use `student.getSurname()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`StudentClass.getSurname()` is not defined as a static method. You need to declare an instance of that class in order to be able to call it.

```
StudentClass myClass = new StudentClass(/* whatever params you need*/);
String surname = myClass.getSurname();
```

keep in mind you need to do this for all those methods, as they're at the instance level.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentDetails.size(); i++){
             StudentClass = studentDetails.get(i);
             System.out.println( StudentClass.getForename() + " " +
             StudentClass.getSurname() + " received a " + StudentClass.getGrade() +
             " for their Student Mark of " + StudentClass.getMark() + "." );
            }
```

Change the code above to:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < studentDetails.size(); i++){
        StudentClass student = studentDetails.get(i);
        System.out.println( student.getForename() + " " +
        student.getSurname() + " received a " + student.getGrade() +
                 " for their Student Mark of " + student.getMark() + "." );
   }
```

See if the error will be gone. The compiler was complaining because you were trying to invoke an instance level (non-static) method on the class itself (rather than an instance of the class).

Answer (score 0):

Non-static method in java cannot be accessed with out an object

Just try like this,

```
else{
         for(int i = 0; i < studentDetails.size(); i++){
             studentDetails.get(i) = new StudentClass();
             System.out.println( studentDetails.get(i).getForename() + " " +
             studentDetails.get(i).getSurname() + " received a " + studentDetails.get(i).getGrade() +
             " for their Student Mark of " + studentDetails.get(i).getMark() + "." );
            }
        }
```